# Sibling components communication Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm in angular 4, working with siblings, no parents or child, just siblings.

One brother is getting the data, particularly the id from the URL

```
  public getId () {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // console.log (id); //working! 
    return id
    }
```

The other one tried to do the same to save us all this... but he doesnt get the Id, even if he is in the same route. I dont know why.

So, now I want to send the ID from the sibling one to the sibling two. After some research, I found a lot of example for child and parents, but in my case they are siblings, so it looks like passing the data through a services is the best option, I followed this [tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/).

But something doesn't work fine, **Where is my problem?**

**Component one:** This is the one with the responsibility to get the ID from the URL

```
  urlId: number;
  public getId () {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    // console.log (id); //working! 
    return id
    }
ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = +this.getId ();                   
    this.taskService.newId(id)
}
```

**The service**: this one update the noId with the function `newID()`

```
  private noId = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  defaultId = this.noId.asObservable();

  newId(urlId: number) {
    this.noId.next(urlId);
    console.log (urlId); // this still working
  }
```

**Component two:** this one, after running the `onInit()` function, should get the data, but nothing is happening.

```
urlId: number;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.taskService.defaultId.subscribe(urlId => this.urlId = urlId)
     console.log (this.urlId); //return 0, or the same value as private noId 
    }
```

So, in component 2, I am not getting refreshed data. **What is wrong?**

Comment: Your `console.log` in component two happens *outside* the subscription, at which point `this.urlId` will not have the latest value.

Comment: try console.log inside subscribe: `subscribe(urlId => { 
this.urlId = urlId ;
console.log (this.urlId);
})`

Comment: How do your sibling interact with eachother? If you **click** or something you can use a simple **setter** and **getter** in your **shared** service.

Comment: easy! thanks @Dhyey

Comment: @Swoox with the `onInit()` function

Comment: @ValRob how you trigger the onInit() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a subject in service.

```
public idSub$ = new Subject<number>();
```

In your sibling component where you getting id just paste this code.

```
this.taskService.idSub$.next(id);
```

In sibling component where you want id use following code:

```
this.taskService.subscribe(id => {
  console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Just exactly what I was looking, In fact, I wrote a [blog](https://josuevalrob.com/send-variable-between-siblings) about this topic, thank you very much!. Can you Upvote my question please??